# Probabilistic comparison of two mixture models?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, t-test, gaussian-mixture-distribution

Given two gaussian mixture models (GMMs) with different degrees of freedom, is there a way to determine the probability that one is generated from the other? That is, can we give a probability to the hypothesis that the two distributions are actually the same?

My current approach is to use a correlation score, which is easy to calculate but is not really a probability:

$$
C(p_1,p_2) = -\log \left[ \frac{\int p_1(x)p_2(x)dx}{\int p_1^2(x)+p_2^2(x)dx}\right]
$$
For two GMMs $p_1(\boldsymbol r)=\sum_i\pi_i\phi_i(\boldsymbol r|\boldsymbol \mu_i,\boldsymbol \Sigma_i)$ and $p_2(\boldsymbol r)=\sum_j\pi_j\phi_j(\boldsymbol r|\boldsymbol \mu_j,\boldsymbol \Sigma_j)$ we have:
$$
\int p_1p_2 = \sum_{i,j} \pi_i\pi_j\int\phi_i(\boldsymbol r)\phi_j(\boldsymbol r)d\boldsymbol r
$$
The final integral is straightforward to compute because the product of two gaussians is another gaussian. I like this function because it's analytic, but it really doesn't tell us a probability. One additional thought is to use a [multivariate t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling's_T-squared_distribution) but this seems to only be useful for comparing two normal distributions. I need to compare two mixtures with unequal degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing two distributions, not two random variables, so I'm not sure where "probability" would come into play. The closest thing to what you describe is the [Kullback-Leibler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence), which measures the amount of extra information one would need to encode with one distribution a sample produced by the other.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit confusing for me. Doesn't the two-way t-test, for example, give you the probability that two distributions are the same thing?

Comment: No, it compares two samples.

Comment: OK I'll give you the answer, that was very helpful. I think I need to rework my question :)